# Lower quality photos in burst mode

Tags: sharpness, sports, tips, burst-mode

I took some photos of high speed skating and as there was too much motion involved, I switched to burst mode (continuous shots) hoping I'll get some good shots. But the sharpness of those taken in burst mode is not as good as others shots(also involving same amount of motion).

Is it a coincidence or there is some genuine limitation of burst mode? I've a Nikon D5100.

PS: Any other tips for skating photos?

Comment: What focus mode are you using?

Comment: I use manual focus.

Comment: A faster frame rate doesn't mean a faster shutter speed, it just means a shorter gap between each exposure at the same shutter speed.

Comment: Your question can not be answered without knowing what specific camera you were using as this could have some bearing on the results you have referred to in your question.

Comment: I use a Nikon D5100. I was just looking if there is some known limitation of burst mode, but apparently there's not (otherwise you guys would be aware of it). So the problem must be me, I'll figure it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: Sometimes (model dependant) the camera will purposely reduce the *resolution* to keep up with the writing speed. But I think this type of quality isn't the one you're referring to. Can you post examples of good/poor quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burst mode gives the camera less time to adjust focus while still maintaining the burst.  On some cameras you can actually alter the priority of achieving solid focus vs keeping the burst rate up.  On a normal shot, it will normally take it's time to focus, but you may get a longer lag time then before it can take the shot.

Additionally, you may have further camera shake with burst do to the repeated mirror movement which could be a factor and you may be actively moving the camera while using burst rather than holding still for a single shot.

Movement of the subject, movement of the camera and subject out of focus can all be the source of sharpness issues and without more experimentation or sample images it isn't really possible to tell what the main contributing factors were.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your camera. I would suggest looking into the details of the burst mode for your specific camera.

Some cameras may lower the resolution or quality of the images taken in burst mode to lower processing time needed to keep up with the higher rate of exposures.

When taking photos of action you really need to pay attention to your shutter speed to limit the blur caused my motion (which you may or may not want)